# Как устранить ошибку приобработке пакета python3-urllib3

Tags: linux, bash, apt, pkg-config

При попытке установить пакеты командой

```
sudo aptitude -y install pkg-config
```

Возникают ошибки

```
При обработке следующих пакетов произошли ошибки:
 python3-urllib3
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
Настраивается пакет python3-urllib3 (1.26.5-1~exp1ubuntu0.1) …
[Errno 20] Not a directory: '/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/urllib3/util/__pycache__/__init__.cpython-310.pyc.139833576745136'dpkg: ошибка при обработке пакета python3-urllib3 (--configure):
 installed python3-urllib3 package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1
При обработке следующих пакетов произошли ошибки:
 python3-urllib3
```

Посмотрел, действительно `__pycache__` это не папка

```
evgeny@kubuntu:/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/urllib3/util$ ll __pycache__
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 957 мая 26  2021 __pycache__
```

Как решить подобную проблему?